# how do I use .htaccess in a two teir login

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I am working on a development site, that has a published production site. There is a new lead on the site. I work for him. He has asked me to lock out the Development Site via .htaccess. Which I have done (testuser/testpass). On the published production site, there is no login necessary to access the homepage, but on the development site there now is. Simple enough.

So here is the problem. On the production website there is a password protected subdirectory "RESTRICTED" protected by .htaccess (authuser/authpass). He would like the "TESTUSER" to re-authenticate when accessing "RESTRICTED" ~as~ "AUTHUSER".

I am not sure if .htaccess can do this because it normally authorizes for files and directories that are below it.

An attempt to visually describe this is below.

```
HOMEPAGE (for testuser) or 403 for others ~including~ authuser
  |__ Current Events
        |__ more pages
  |__ Calendar
  |__ Some other page
  |__ RESTRICTED (to authuser) or return to HOMEPAGE
  |__ Contact Us
```

The question is: Is it possible? He seems to think it should be, I am uncertain.

I have tried the obvious, an .htaccess in the WEBROOT with index.html with testuser in it... And an .htaccess file in RESTRICTED specifically requiring "Require authuser" from a different .htpasswd.

Please help, Thanks in advance, :wave:
-Dej